# Summarizing at multiple levels of hierarchy

Tags: r, dplyr, purrr

I've got a dataset with four levels: observations (i.e. a period in which a teacher is observed), teachers, schools, school divisions. Observations are nested within teachers, who are nested within schools, etc.

Each row in the data corresponds to an instance a teacher is observed.

At each level of the hierarchy, I want to compute the `mean`, `sd`, `min`, and `max` for each of several variables (`x1`, `x2`, and `x3` in the simulated data, but there are ~12 in the actual data). And I want all of these summaries in a single dataframe.

The code below will do it, but it feels clunky to me. More specifically, a few things bothering me are:

1. I couldn't figure out how to `rename` within the function I wrote using the `group_var` value, so I resorted to manually doing this outside of the functions.
2. I end up creating multiple dataframes and then using `left_join` to join them together at the end (again manually).
3. Ultimately, I feel like there is probably a way (possibly using something in `purrr` to "peel back" layers of hierarchy and aggregate, but it's eluding me.

Any advice on how to streamline this, and particularly how to pass the `group_var` values to `rename_at`, would be much appreciated!

```
library(tidyverse)
library(treemap)

df <- random.hierarchical.data(n = 200, depth = 4) %>%
  rename(div = index1,
         sch = index2,
         teacher = index3,
         obs = index4,
         x1 = x) %>%
  mutate(x2 = rlnorm(200),
         x3 = rlnorm(200))

sum_func <- function(data, sum_vars, ...) {
  group_vars <- enquos(...)

  data %>%
    group_by(!!!group_vars) %>%
    summarize_at(vars(sum_vars),
                 list(
                   ~mean(., na.rm = TRUE),
                   ~sd(., na.rm = TRUE),
                   ~min(., na.rm = TRUE),
                   ~max(., na.rm = TRUE)
                 )) %>%
    ungroup()
}

use_vars <- c("x1", "x2", "x3")

teacher_sum <- sum_func(data = df, sum_vars = use_vars, div, sch, teacher) %>%
  rename_at(vars(-c("teacher", "sch", "div")), ~str_replace_all(., "^", "teacher_"))

sch_sum <- sum_func(df, sum_vars = use_vars, div, sch) %>%
  rename_at(vars(-c("sch", "div")), ~str_replace_all(., "^", "sch_"))

div_sum <- sum_func(df, sum_vars = use_vars, div) %>%
  rename_at(vars(-c("div")), ~str_replace_all(., "^", "div_"))

full <- teacher_sum %>%
  left_join(sch_sum, by = c("sch", "div")) %>%
  left_join(div_sum, by = "div")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have been quite close. The code below works yet I am unsure how to automate the joining completely since the logic is not clear to me

```
sum_func <- function(data, sum_vars, replacement, ...) {
  group_vars <- enquos(...)

  data %>%
    group_by(!!!group_vars) %>%
    summarize_at(vars(sum_vars),
                 list(
                   ~mean(., na.rm = TRUE),
                   ~sd(., na.rm = TRUE),
                   ~min(., na.rm = TRUE),
                   ~max(., na.rm = TRUE)
                 )) %>%
    ungroup() %>%
    rename_at(vars(-c(!!!group_vars)), 
              ~str_replace_all(., "^", replacement))
}

use_vars <- c("x1", "x2", "x3")

teacher_sum <- sum_func(data = df, 
                        sum_vars = use_vars, 
                        replacement = "teacher_",
                        div, sch, teacher)

sch_sum <- sum_func(data = df, 
                    sum_vars = use_vars, 
                    replacement = "sch_",
                    div, sch)
div_sum <- sum_func(df, 
                    sum_vars = use_vars, 
                    replacement = "div_",
                    div)
```

Comment: Thanks! This is really helpful, and actually the more I think about it, I may not actually want to join all of the tables together.

Comment: Cheers mate! :)